# Is it possible to have my website change ip address?

Tags: ip, website

I was thinking about making a website on my Apache server. But it costs a lot to have a static IP/domain name and all of that. This probably sounds crazy, but does anyone know if it is possible to have your website change to whatever IP address your service provider gives you? Or is this something that has already been tried and failed? Probably sounds crazy since it would eliminate the need to buy a static IP address, just some random idea that came into my mind.

Comment: Ouro below is correct, and hosting at home will be a breach of contract too.

Comment: I don't think hosting a website on a home connection is a considered a breach of terms of service in 2015. It would be silly for any ISP to enforce that clause, if it still exists at all - with the advent of video streaming that uses much more resources.

Comment: @cloneman Most ISPs still have things in their agreements that you can not host services for commercial purposes. They want you to sign a business class contract to be able to do that.

Comment: @ScottChaimberlain the Internet is a big place, and most ISP's do not have those terms in there agreement - at least in this part of the world.  (and indeed those terms may be of no effect if they just in fineprint).

Answer (score 5):

This is what dynamic DNS services are for. The reason they aren't used for production web servers is that, whenever the IP changes, the site will appear to be down briefly (minutes to hours depending on the service) while the DNS record is updated and redistributed.